# Why wouldn't Google be able to read AJAX generated JSON-LD schema.org markup parsed from a Google sheet?

Tags: google-search-console, javascript, schema.org, ajax, json-ld

There's a lot going on in that question so here's a breakdown:

1. Every Google sheet has a JSON version that can be parsed ([example](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1Mt7aQrWAX07fw7-NtUxwSTiw-6ij03yq_-ZBDFrEgRo/1/public/values?alt=json)).
2. I've parsed that data using pure JS and AJAX, and generated schema.org markup for events in the form of JSON-LD ([see output](https://centaurtheatre.com/the-watershed.html)).
3. Google's SDTT is can read and validate the markup ([see results](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url=https://centaurtheatre.com/the-watershed.html)). However, the markup is not showing up in Webmaster.

So why isn't it showing up in Webmaster?

### Here's what I've considered:

1. *Google ignores JSON-LD markup that's generated via JavasSript.*

   - There is other JSON-LD schema.org markup on the page that's generated via JavasSript that Webmaster has been able to read. So that's not it.
2. *Google can't read JSON-LD markup that's generated via AJAX.*

   - Though I can't find anything on this, I don't see why Google would [be able to read AJAX](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) generated content, but then struggle with JSON-LD.

What am I missing?

Comment: How long have you waited for webmaster tools to update? it can a several months for those to reflect in Webmaster Tools and even longer in Search Results, and even longer with sites with high volume of URLS.

Comment: Several months!? What kind of sites are you working with? When was the last time you've used webmaster? I've never had it take longer than 72 hours on any site I've worked on. Results have also updated for similar pages that aren't adding json through ajax already so this doesn't seem to be an issue of time.

Comment: I use Webmaster Tools daily and I administrate 75+ sites on behalf of customers... but anyhow, I'll explain. Google needs to discover new microdata or updated microdata, so in order for them to discover changes Google must revisit the page, sites with low authority or those with thousands of pages can take a long time for Google to revisit the particular page(s). You may be able to speed up the process using Google fetch as we know that speeds up indexing, however I'm unsure if it updates webmaster tools, because data from index to WMT is not realtime and often delayed by several days.

Comment: WMT can be fast at times and slow at other times... also speed of provided data can vary from site to site including other reasons such as some pages will be crawled more often than others depending on page rank for that page or how often the content gets updated. If rich snippet testing tool is reading it, then I see no reason why is Googlebot not... and I'd point this at WMT not updating as you would like it.

Comment: I added the markup manually without parsing it and it indexed the page in 24 hours so there's something that Google isn't liking about the way that the markup is being generated from the Google sheet.